Property of edge-vertex transitive graphs
Recently I am reading a paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00858) with respect to edge-vertex transitive graphs. What is the property of the graph that is edge transitive and vertex transitive? I know little about this definition :(... Thanks for your answer or comment or if you can give me a note on this definition (edge-vertex transitive).
Does the following holds for edge-vertex transitive (edge transitive and vertex transitive) graph $G$? (If not, does it hold when $G$ is bipartite?)

Let $N_v^k(G)$ denote the $k$'th neighbour of $v$, i.e. vertices which is connected with $v$ by a $k$-edges path. For any two vertices $u,v\in G$: Does $|N_v^k(G)|=|N_u^k(G)|$ for every integer $k$?

For any two vertex set $A,B\subseteq G$ with $|A|=|B|$: Does $|\cup_{v\in A}N_v^k(G)|=|\cup_{u\in B}N_u^k(G)|$ holds?

Is there any properties of edge-vertex transitive graphs which is usually been used?




holds even for usual vertex-transitive graphs, and doesn’t hold in the bipartite setting.



doesn’t hold in either setting. Take A two adjacent vertices, and B two far away vertices (with different labels in the bipartite setting). Then the union of neighborhood is smaller for A than B, as the neighborhood around points of A intersects.



Lovasz theta of an edge-transitive graph is realized on its adjacency matrix. A chromatic number and fractional chromatic number of a vertex-transitive n-vertex graph have ratio at most log(n).

